# Turning a list into an actors (Greenfoot)

Tags: java, list, collision

I am working on a shooter game for my school programming project and using collision detection with actors.

later on I realized that I need to use another method that can return all actors in an area but the only problem is it returns a list. I have no idea how to use a list and need to turn each element of the list into an actor

Here is the section of the code:

```
MyWorld w = (MyWorld) getWorld();
    List<Actor> a = getObjectsInRange(20, null) ;
    //if it hits the soldier
    if ( a  instanceof Soldier)
    {
        Soldier s = (Soldier) a;
        //kill the enemy
        s.die();
        //add 100 score to the enemy
        w.addScore(100);
        //if the weapon is not laser
        if (weaponId != 2) 
        {
            //getting the world to make the bullet able to fire again
            w.setBulletLive(false); 
            //remove the bullet
            getWorld().removeObject(this); 

        }
    }
    // if it hits the enemy
    else if (a instanceof EnemyWeapon)
    {
        EnemyWeapon g = (EnemyWeapon) a; 
        //intercept the missile
        g.intercepted();
```

Comment: What exactly is an Actor and how does it relate to the other objects? You probably want to start with for (Actor actor : actors ) {core here}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through the list of actors you can do the following:

```
for (Actor actor : listActors) {
    // here you should put your logic.
    ...
}
```